# In VC++ what is the #pragma equivalent of /O2 compiler option (optimize for speed)

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-optimization

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f8h5cxt.aspx),

> /O2 (Maximize Speed)

is equivalent to

> /Og/Oi/Ot/Oy/Ob2/Gs/GF/Gy

and according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k%28VS.80%29.aspx) again, the following pragma

> #pragma optimize( "[optimization-list]", {on | off} )

uses the same letters in its "optimization-list" than the /O compiler option. Available letters for the pragma are:

- **g** - *Enable global optimizations.*
- **p** - *Improve floating-point consistency.*
- **s or t** - *Specify short or fast sequences of machine code.*
- **y** - *Generate frame pointers on the program stack.*

Which ones should I use to have the same meaning as /O2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Microsoft Docs article */O1, /O2 (Minimize Size, Maximize Speed)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o1-o2-minimize-size-maximize-speed?view=vs-2017) says for Visual Studio 2017:

> The /O1 and /O2 compiler options are a quick way to set several
>   specific optimization options at once. The /O1 option sets the
>   individual optimization options that create the smallest code in the
>   majority of cases. The /O2 option sets the options that create the
>   fastest code in the majority of cases. The /O2 option is the default
>   for release builds. This table shows the specific options that are set
>   by /O1 and /O2:
>
> ```
> Option                   Equivalent to
> /O1 (Minimize Size)     /Og /Os /Oy /Ob2 /GF /Gy
> /O2 (Maximize Speed)    /Og /Oi /Ot /Oy /Ob2 /GF /Gy
> ```

[From the Microsoft Docs article */O Options (Optimize Code)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o-options-optimize-code?view=vs-2017):

1. `/Og` enables global optimizations
2. `/Oi` generates intrinsic functions for appropriate function calls.
3. `/Ot` (a default setting) tells the compiler to favor optimizations for speed over optimizations for size.
4. `/Oy` suppresses the creation of frame pointers on the call stack for quicker function calls.
5. `/Ob2` expands functions marked as `inline` or `__inline` and any other function that the compiler chooses

The /G options are:

1. `/GF` (Eliminate Duplicate Strings)
2. `/Gy` (Enable Function-Level Linking)

The `/G` options aren't strictly optimizations, so that leaves us with `/Og` and `/Ot`, plus `#pragma intrinsic` (for item 2 in the list), `#pragma auto_inline` (for item 5 in the list) and possibly `#pragma inline_depth`. See [Microsoft Docs article *Optimization Pragmas and Keywords*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/optimization-pragmas-and-keywords?view=vs-2017)

See also [Microsoft Docs article /Ox (Enable Most Speed Optimizations)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ox-full-optimization?view=vs-2017) which indicates the `/Ox` option is similar to the `/O2` option except that it does not turn on `/GF` nor `/Gy`. See as well [What is the difference between the /Ox and /O2 compiler options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063334/what-is-the-difference-between-the-ox-and-o2-compiler-options)

[The Microsoft Docs article *Compiler options listed by category*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category?view=vs-2017) has a list of compiler options with links as to what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct equivalent.

#pragma optimise("gty", off)

Should cancel for a file, most of the effect of /O2 at the project level, but

#pragma optimise("gty", on)

Just says "use the compiler switch", so you need /O2 or /Og /Ot /Oy.

I can't find pragmas for the /G parts and they do optimisation 'like' things.