# Visual C++ Compiler Optimization Flags: Difference Between /O2 and /Ot

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-optimization, compiler-options

What's the difference between the `/Ot` flag ("favor fast code") and the `/O2` flag ("maximize speed")?

(Ditto with `/Os` and `/O1`.)

Comment: Next you'll want to know the answer to this: [What is the difference between the /Ox and /O2 compiler options?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063334/what-is-the-difference-between-the-ox-and-o2-compiler-options) ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

/O1 and /O2 bundle together a number of options aimed at a larger goal. So /O1 makes a number of code generation choices that favour size; /O2 does the same thing and favours speed.

/O1 includes /Os as well as other options. /O2 includes /Ot as well as other options. Some optimisations are enabled by both /O1 and /O2. And, depending on your program's paging behaviour, /O1 (size) can result in faster speed than /O2 if paging code comes to dominate your perf over instruction execution cost.

A good short summary of the impact of /O1 and /O2 in VC++ 2010 is here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f8h5cxt.aspx

and includes links for other versions of VC.

Martyn

Comment: Thanks for the response, but a question: So what happens if I put `/O1` with `/Ot`? Is it favoring size or speed?

Comment: If you put /O1 and then /Ot in that order (and no subsequent options or pragmas), you get all the other options in O1 and /Os from /O1 is removed and /Ot replaces it. What you then get is a hybrid of size and speed optimisations.

Answer (score 2):

See the [/O1, /O2 (Minimize Size, Maximize Speed)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f8h5cxt.aspx) article at MSDN.

It states that `/O2` is equivalent to:

```
/Og /Oi /Ot /Oy /Ob2 /Gs /GF /Gy
```

So `/O2` enables all the things that `/Ot` does, and some more. Same thing for `/O1` vs. `/Os`, but for size this time.

Answer (score 0):

No difference. `/Ot` is a part of the `/O2` optimizations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9534wye.aspx