# How to speed up exe file with compile?

Tags: c, visual-studio, compilation, processor

I have small c program that I wrote on c use with lot of cpu and compile it with visual studio 17,running on windows.

I want to speed up this exe file without changing the code, only with changing the compilation method.

I don't care about security code ,only speed, I know the OS and processor thatvthis progran will run on it (if it help).

So how can I faster my prigram with changing the compiler/ disable some security flag/ compile it to spesific os/ processor?

Comment: 1. define `...small c program`.  2. try a `release` build instead of a `debug` build to see if that's what you need?

Comment: 200 lines of code, and I use in release

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler doesn't do optimizations by default, you can add some arguments to get the maximum speed from the compiler. You can find all kind of these arguments [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1ack8f1.aspx). In your case probably it is `/O2`.

To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment:

1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box.
2. Click the C/C++ folder.
3. Click the Optimization property page.
4. Modify the Optimization property.

Comment: What is the diffrence between `02` and `0x` what is the maximum optimization? And how I set it in visual studio?

Comment: o2 only optimizes for the speed, but ox optimizes for both speed and compiled binary file size.

Comment: So if I dont care about file size and I only want speed do I need to put 02? What is the default option when compile pn release?

Comment: Yes, you should put O2 for speed. And the default option is [/Ot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9534wye.aspx) is the.

Comment: `ot` is fast code and `02` is very fast code? Is there say about in avarege how much (in %) the speed is between those option?  By the way I saw `For example, the Optimization property, by default, is set to Maximize Speed (/O2) in a Release configuration` here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx

Comment: /o2 enables /ot and other options as well, you can see the difference here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007378/visual-c-compiler-optimization-flags-difference-between-o2-and-ot

Answer (score 0):

In Project -> Properties set the optimization flags to suit you:
[image]

Comment: Mark all choise there as yes? Or only the first?  What are the effect of those changes? Why they are disable by default

Comment: You are showing the debug settings, where optimisation is switched off. Don't the release settings (which the OP is using)  have optimisation enabled by default?