# C array assignment works while out of bounds

Tags: c, arrays

Why is the following code works (`printf()` gets executed) before `i` reaches `14`?  Actually, the execution should fail when `i` goes past the 10th element of the array, no?  Even I I write:

```
  for(i=0; i<100; i++)
```

I still get a Segmentation fault of course but all values are printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void funcX() {
    int i;
    int array[10];

    printf("\tEntering funcX()\n");

    //for(i=0; i<11; i++) { //This works
    //for(i=0; i<12; i++) { //This works
    //for(i=0; i<13; i++) { //This works
    for(i=0; i<14; i++) {   //***This fails****
        array[i]=i;
        printf( "array[i]= %d\n", array[i] );
    }

    printf("\tLeaving funcX()\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("Calling funcX() from main()\n");
    funcX();
    printf("Returning from funcX()\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Compiled on RH Linux using `gcc -m32`.

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: It just happens to work. Writing to unallocated memory is undefined behavior. Eventually, you hit a problem and it crashes. You can't rely on it working outside the allocated memory; it's just a fluke based on your machine's current state.

Comment: Very similar to [Is accessing a global array outside its bound undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26426910/1708801) ... your answer is there, the difference is a global array Vs automatic one but essentially the same otherwise.

Comment: Writing out of bounds is not forbidden, but it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: You are in undefined behaviour territory!! Please move out of the zone fast! I repeat "Undefined Behaviour" ! - Ok, on a serious note, It is undefined behaviour, it may or may not work. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior. Maybe you should try compiling with -Wall switch

Answer (score 3):

on executing

```
for(i=0; i<14; i++) {
```

and for a value of `i` equal to `10`, you're facing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by accessing out-of-bound memory [`array[i]`], the result of which is, well, ***undefined***. *One of the side effects* is segmentation fault. It is not a *must*.

Comment: There is something special at `array[13]` which is causing the Segmentation Fault.