# C: How come I can still access to an empty array?

Tags: c, arrays

While playing around with arrays, and experimented with this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{
  int a[] = {};
  printf ( "%d\n", sizeof(a) );
  printf ( "%d\n", a[0] );
  printf ( "%d\n", a[1] );
  printf ( "%d\n", a[10] );
  printf ( "%d\n", a[100] );
}
```

And somehow, it compiled successfully without errors got this result:

```
0
-1216614400
134513834
-1080435356
-1080430834
```

How come I am able to access an empty array at any index that should have no size?

Comment: See [Is accessing a global array outside its bound undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26426910/1708801)

Comment: "*at any index that should have no size*", what do you mean?

Comment: Which compiler? I am guessing `clang` but perhaps `gcc`?

Comment: Something to meditate on: `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)` - so much so that you can write `10[a]` instead of `a[10]` (not that you should, of course). So you're just accessing locations in memory, not calling methods on some fancy data structure implementation…

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
printf ( "%d\n", a[0] );
printf ( "%d\n", a[1] );
printf ( "%d\n", a[10] );
printf ( "%d\n", a[100] );
```

produces  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by accessing out-of-bound memory.