# What exactly happens if I declare a 10 elements array and try to access a bigger position within it?

Tags: c, arrays

It just happened to me. A bug. I set a 5 element array and a position variable to scroll through all its index:

```
int matematica[5];
int pos = 0;
```

and then I had my loop working just ok. Like this:

```
while (pos < 5) {
    printf("Entre com o número da matrícula do %dº aluno: \n", pos+1);
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num != 35)
        matematica[pos] = num;
    pos++;
}
```

Everything working like a charm. After that, I had do the same to 150 positions, so I changed the while loop from `while (pos < 5)` to `while (pos < 150)` but forgot to do the same with the array. What happened then is the object of my question itself. The program didn't crash or something, it just happened that the `printf` and `scanf` statements run a bit more than 5 times then stops (sometimes 8 times, sometimes 7...)

Why does that happens. I of course fixed it later, but I still can't grasp the logic behind that bug.

Comment: Pretty much anything at all can happen. The [standard hyperbole](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) is that the compiler is allowed to make demons fly out your nose.

Comment: You invoked undefined behavior, which by its very definition cannot be definitively explained.

Comment: "Why does that happens " - It happens for no definitive reason whatsoever. Thus the nature of *undefined behavior*, which is precisely what you told your program to invoke: nonsense.

Comment: Related to [Is accessing a global array outside its bound undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26426910/1708801) maybe a duplicate

Comment: Is this array global or local to a function?

Comment: Learn about `virtual memory layout` on linux will help you understand what might happan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C standard says this triggers Undefined behavior,

anything could happen.

- It could appear to work "correctly"
- it could terminate with an error code.
- it could do something unexpected.

This type of bug is called a buffer overrun, and these can often lead to arbitrary code execution (which is a special subclass of "something unexpected")

In your example `pos` probably occupies the same memory as `matematica[5]`, (because most (all?) compilers pack global variables together much like fields in a struct) so depending on what number you enter in the sixth  place the loop may stop or continue,  negative numbers could cause
interesting results.

Comment: `pos` is not necessarily after (i.e. a larger address) than `matematica`.  It depends on which way the stack (I'm assuming this is a local variable) grows and probably other factors (i.e. it's compiler dependent).

Comment: I've not encounterd a compiler that arranged globals differently when they are of the same base type, but there is no guarantee.but yeah, in in a auto (=local) variable addressing is even less predictable.

Answer (score -3):

When you declare your array to be the array of 5 integers, you reserve a chunk of memory which holds it and then, you receive a pointer to it (which you can use however you want). When you call for an array like matematica[0], then you point to the beginning of an array and use value, which is out there. Then, when you call matematica[6] (which is outside the boundaries), you still reach the very same memory, but outside your array. It is totally legal, but it is unknown what is stored there. When you upload any other value there, you might overwrite your own data and cause weird bugs, and when you try to read it, it will be probably a random number. It will not crash, but you are warned :)

Comment: `matematica[5]` is also outside the boundaries

Comment: @FiddlingBits in the C standard, *allocate* only refers to space allocated by `malloc` and friends; although it's common usage to say things like "stack allocation" or "automatic allocation" or "static allocation"

Comment: "It is totally legal" - no, it's not. Accessing memory outside the array is only one possible result; it is not at all guaranteed behavior.

Comment: Well, right.. Changed it to not make any unspoken, misleading suggestions. By 'totally legal' i meant that if we don't fall outside memory, we can call it and it probably won't crash.

Comment: "you still reach the very same memory" may be a common experience, but is not specified behavior of C.  "It is totally legal" is outright wrong.  "It will not crash" may/may not happen .

Comment: There might not be any memory outside the array. For example, if the array is at the end of the address space; or if the OS gives processes a virtual address space (modern OSs do that) and the addresses after the array are not mapped to any physical memory.

Comment: Why did they downvote @irchris102 . Though "totally legal" may not be the most appropriate wording, his answer is just right -by the way the only one that gave me a real insight of what happened - the concept behind is just right. That's precisely the object of my question.

I think Stack Overflow should prevent people from downvoting without having answered the question, seems like people just read in a hurry and just straight clik "Downvote".

Comment: @irchris102, accessing memory outside the bounds of an array that is on the stack is accessing the memory of the other variables on the stack, the function return address, the variables passed from the calling function, the variables and return address of any called functions, the stack frame pointers, etc etc etc.   What the specific result will be could be most anything.  That is why it is called 'undefined behavior'.

Comment: @Ezequiel Barbosa this answer is not just right as it asserts functionality that is not defined.  Even it this answer matches your experience, to ascribe behavior based upon experience and contradicted by specification leads to future coding pitfalls in assuming "you still reach the very same memory" and "It will not crash".  Many a _good_  answer about Undefined Behavior (UB) describes what likely happened  in OP's case, but does not contend that is proscribed behavior like this one does.

Comment: Ok, just to finish this case once and for all... Sometimes I believe that simplified answer is more educational for a person than specifying dozens of different behaviours which might happen. I strongly believe that my example is much simplier to imagine and memorize than just saying it is undefined and trying to point out every possibility and, in fact, has the very same outcome - person who imagine that is not likely to mess with other variables' (pointers' etc.) or reach boundaries of memory. If question was REALLY about all possibilities, one would just look at docs without asking here...