# Why arrays can be invoked out of bounds sometimes

Tags: c, arrays, indexing

I wrote a `C` codes :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int i;
 int a[4];
  for( i =0;i<5;i++)
 {
  a[i]=i;
  printf("a[%d]:%d ",i,a[i]);

  }
 return 0;
 }
```

I used gcc to compile it and succeed to run,the result is :

> a[0]:0 a[1]:1 a[2]:2 a[3]:3 a[4]:4

But you can see array `a` has size of 4,from 0 to 3,i haven't create extra memory to refer to `a[4]`,and unexpectedly it run and seem no errors.In `Java`,i find if arrays' index out of bounds,it'll throws exception.I just don't know why in C language it just run like right.

Comment: See [Is accessing a global array outside its bound undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26426910/1708801) the specifics are slightly different but the answers cover all the same ground an answer to this question would.

Comment: Because C has no bounds checking on arrays. When writing to `a[4]` you're just writing somewhere in memory. If you're lucky, you will get a `Segfault`, which will tell you that something is wrong in memory. in most cases, you're just corrupting whatever data was there (and it can have effects way later in your application ... and then "Happy debugging").

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour `a[4]` is not global in this case!

Comment: @HappyCoder yes, that is why I said *the specifics are slightly different* but the answers are very complete and a complete answer to this will cover almost all the same ground.

Comment: Think abut the meaning of **undefined** as in _undefined behaviour_. (This is what you are invoking).

Comment: @Olaf yes,I know what is undefined,I just have invoked an undefined index which  is out of bounds,but I think what I have invoked may be something have defined in stack if index  refer to the position in stack.

Comment: No, the index is not undefined. UB is invoked once you **dereference** an out-of bounds pointer. **think again!** C does not even have a concept of a stack.

Comment: @Olaf  Thanks to correct. Personal speaking,I have misunderstood segment as stack.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't check array boundaries. *Segmentation fault* will only happen when you read or write to memory your program  don't have access to. Simply going past array boundaries won't make your program crash.

But accessing index out of bounds invokes *undefined behaviour* .

Comment: Correct but incomplete.

Comment: @immibis Yes , I  am modifying it . Please take a look again.