# Inserting a value for an array using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I used this code to insert values for array `data`, but when I tried inserting the values `8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`(the first number 8 is the size of the array), the output was `00000000` instead of the input values `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`. Any idea how I can make the program work?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int n,i,*data;

  scanf("%d", &n);

  data=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);//data[size]

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
     scanf("%d", &data[i]);
  }

  for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
     printf("%d",data[n]);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo `printf("%d",data[n]);` --> `printf("%d",data[i]);`

Comment: I suggest that you do yourself a favor and learn how to use debugger. It will help you to find trivial mistakes like this quickly.

Comment: Also `i<=n` --> `i<n`. Voting to close this as simple typo.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this part :

```
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    printf("%d",data[n]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

to :

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d",data[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

What you do now is iterating but not using the variable `i` as index. Instead, you constantly try to print only `data[n]`. This is accessing index ***out of bounds*** as in [c](/questions/tagged/c), an array's indexes start from `0` and reach `n-1`, where `n` is the array's size. This can cause [tag: undefined-behavior] of your program.

So your `for` loop will either have to be :

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

or :

```
for(i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)
```

---

Also, take a look on this [link on why you should not cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Moreover, make sure that you always check the result of `malloc`, like this :

```
data=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
if (data == NULL)
    printf("Error in dynamically allocating memory.\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The print loop should use `i` as index and not `n` as yours
2. The loop have to go up to `n-1`, so correct condition have to be `i<n`. Your code access the "array" out of bounds which invokes [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26427201/3436922)
3. You always have to check function return values.
4. Side note: with [c](/questions/tagged/c) [you shouldn't cast malloc return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    size_t n,i;
    int *data;

    printf("Insert number of items: ");
    scanf("%zu", &n);

    data=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

    if (data != NULL)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("Insert value for item %zu: ", i+1);
            scanf("%d", &data[i]);
        }

        printf("You inserted: ");

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            printf("%d ",data[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed allocating memory\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```