# C array dynamic memory has no upper limit

Tags: arrays, c, memory-management

I have my code here:

```
int main(){
  printf("%lu\n",(1 * sizeof(int)));
  int* hello=malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
  hello[1000000]=10;
  printf("%d \n",hello[1000000]);
  printf("%lu \n", sizeof(hello));

  int* goodbye=malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
  printf("%lu \n",sizeof(goodbye));

  hello=goodbye;

  printf("%lu \n",sizeof(hello));

  hello=realloc(hello,20);

  hello[1]=0;

  printf("%lu \n",sizeof(hello));
}
```

It outputs this:

4
10
8
8
8
8

This throws has no warnings or errors, which is strange to me because I allocate only 4 bytes for the array hello, but can access hello[1000000].

Also, I tried to resize hello with goodbye, but the size stays the same. At line 10, I do hello=goodbye; which should resize it? I'm a little new to c memory stuff. Realloc also does not change the size of my array. I am trying to make "hello" be a dynamically sized array. What am I doing wrong here?

The code is supposed to be barebones reallocating memory and changing the size of an int array.

Comment: FWIW - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426910/is-accessing-a-global-array-outside-its-bound-undefined-behavior

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)

Comment: given some `int array[20]` and `int *pt = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));`, `sizeof array` is `sizeof int * 20` and `sizeof pt` is just `sizeof(int*)`

Answer (score 5):

> This throws has no warnings or errors, which is strange to me because I allocate only 4 bytes for the array hello, but can access hello[1000000].

This is undefined behaviour. You got (un)lucky and it happened to work for you this time. This is not guaranteed however, and you should never rely on this kind of behaviour.

> Also, I tried to resize hello with goodbye, but the size stays the same.

The `8` you're seeing is the size of a pointer, not the size of the thing it is pointing to. No matter how much memory you allocate, a pointer to that memory will always be the same size.

> At line 10, I do hello=goodbye; which should resize it? I'm a little new to c memory stuff.

This is not resizing it, this is just making `hello` point to the same location as `goodbye`.

A drawing might help.

Before, you have this:

```
hello             goodbye
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
v                    v
MEMORY 1          MEMORY 2
```

After doing `hello = goodbye`, you have this:

```
hello             goodbye
|                     |
\-----------------\   |
                  |   |
                  v   v
MEMORY 1         MEMORY 2
```

i.e., `hello` now points to the same spot as `goodbye`.

> Realloc also does not change the size of my array. I am trying to make "hello" be a dynamically sized array. What am I doing wrong here?

Realloc does change the size of the array, you're not not looking at the size of the array, you're looking at the size of a pointer, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

> This throws has no warnings or errors, which is strange to me because I allocate only 4 bytes for the array hello, but can access hello[1000000].

You're in a territory known as "undefined behavior". C does not *guarantee* that your program will crash in such a scenario. It could be that `hello[1000000]` happens to fall on an address that's valid for other reasons. In doing so, it could corrupt memory that has some other important purpose.

On my machine, it crashed. On https://godbolt.org/ (a tool that's used to investigate programs and compilers), it also crashed.

> Also, I tried to resize hello with goodbye, but the size stays the same. At line 10, I do hello=goodbye; which should resize it?

You didn't resize it. You still have a memory allocation of size `1 * sizeof(int))`. `hello` used to point to it, but now it no longer does, but it's still there in memory, taking up space. You created a new allocation of size `100 * sizeof(int)` and made `hello` point to *that* instead.

> Realloc also does not change the size of my array. I am trying to make "hello" be a dynamically sized array. What am I doing wrong here?

As long as you properly keep track of the size and properly `realloc`, you're on the right path to making a variable sized array. In particular, as long as `realloc(hello,20);` succeeds, you now have memory to safely store 20 bytes worth of data (i.e. five 4-byte `int`s).

You may want to consider defining a struct, which can hold two items: a pointer to the buffer you allocated, and a `size_t` indicating its current size. When you need a bigger array, realloc and update the size.

The problem that you're seeing comes from `sizeof(hello)` - that doesn't actually check the size of the array, but simply indicates the size of the pointer itself. On my machine, the size of a pointer is eight bytes, so it always prints 8.