# boost build - specify compiler options when using Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-options, boost-build

Update:
Now, I use

```
using msvc : 14.0 : : <compileflags>/O1 ;
```

in my project-config.jam. The behavior is what I expect.
But when I replace /O1 to /Ox, the .lib is same as /O2.
/Ox doesn't work correctly!!!

Origin:
I use this command

```
b2.exe variant=release
```

but how do I force boost build to use /Ox instead of /O2?
(The default setting for release builds is /O2, but I want /Ox)
P.S., I try

```
using msvc : 14.0 : : /Ox ;
```

in my project-config.jam, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you want /Ox? You know [it is essentially the same as /O2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063334/what-is-the-difference-between-the-ox-and-o2-compiler-options), right? The only difference is /O2 also enables string pooling and function-level linking. Why would you *not* want either of those?

Comment: @CodyGray In my view, string pooling is slower. (But it is still debatable.)

Answer (score 0):

See the tutorial [here](http://www.boost.org/build/tutorial.html).

The section of interest:

> <cflags>    ... Pass flags to C compiler.
>
> <cxxflags>  ... Pass flags to C++ compiler

Comment: Thank you. But I use <compileflags> finally.